# How to treat long Data uri in codes

Tags: javascript, base64, phaser-framework, data-uri, base64url

I use data URI, base64 to add images and videos to my games, but I found if I want to make a game with multiple videos it will be really bad code with more than 500 lines for each video, so is there any advice to treat this type of file, what I really do that I make a Mixin file and I make multiple functions that return base64.

```
export default{
    stage1(){
        return "data:video/mp4;base64,AAAAIGZ0eXBpc29tAAACAGlzb21pc28yYXZjMW1wNDEAAAAIZnJlZQAFkAdtZGF0AAADAAYF///........."
    },
    stage2(){
        return "data:video/mp4;base64,AAAAIGZ0eXBpc29tAAACAGlzb21pc28yYXZjMW1wNDEAAAAIZnJlZQAFkAdtZGF0AAADAAYF///........."
    },
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer to include a short info to a webpack demo, I hope it helps. Just wanted to see how it works with webpack 5 and thought I could share my demo.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a bundler like *(webpack, parcel, rollup, browserify,...)* you can programm in several files and before deployment the bundler will combine all files into an single file *(and minifiy it)*.

Using a bundler like *webpack* you can create a json file with all dataurl's like:

```
// filename data.json
{
    "video1": "data:video/mp4;base64,AAAA...", 
    "video2": "data:video/mp4;base64,AAAA...", 
    "video3": "data:video/mp4;base64,AAAA...",
    // ...
}
```

in the app script:

```
 import videoData from './data.json';

 ...
     stage1(){
         return videoData.video1;
     }
     stage2(){
         return videoData.video2;
     }
 ...
```

and in the application file you can import teh json-file, and it will be integrated on the bundler build action. *And create a **single file** with all files for the application.*

For details on webpack and how to setup your project [checkout the documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/). It is too long to describe it in an answer, and there are already good articles / video's out there. *(but you can also use any other bundler)*

*I my answer points you in the right direction.*

> **Extra Info:** If you use webpack you would need to use the plugins "html-webpack-plugin" and "html-inline-script-webpack-plugin"

> **btw.:** you can use webpack also to inline assets *(images, video, ...)* into a file, without the need for you to convert them to base64 yourself. *([link to the documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/))*

**Update:**

A small demo project *(if you have **node** and **npm** installed)*:

Install with **npm** these packages

- html-inline-script-webpack-plugin
- html-webpack-plugin
- webpack
- webpack-cli

than create a basic config file for webpack:

```
// webpack.config.js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlInlineScriptPlugin = require('html-inline-script-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "scripts/app.js"),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    },
    module:{
        rules: [{
            test: /\.(mp4|png)/,
            type: 'asset/inline'
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin(),
        new HtmlInlineScriptPlugin(),
    ],
};
```

here a demo app code:

```
// app.js
import Phaser from './phaser.min.js';

import videoFile from '../media/video.mp4';
import imageFile from '../media/demo.png';

let base64ImageFile = imageFile;
let base64VideoFile = videoFile;

let config = {
    scene: { 
        preload: function(){
            this.textures.addBase64('demo', base64ImageFile);
            this.load.video('video', base64VideoFile);
        },
        create: function() { 
            this.add.text(10, 10, 'DEMO')
                .setOrigin(0); 
            this.add.image(10, 30, 'demo')
                .setScale(.25)
                .setOrigin(0);
            this.add.video(300, 30, 'video')
                .setScale(.5)
                .setOrigin(0);
        } 
    }
};

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

The project structure for the demo would look like this:

[image: screenshot project folder structure]

And it would create just one output html-file, all other files are inlined.

Comment: Are you sure about the video thing? because I use URl-loader and it gives me this message when I try to import videos:

client:159 ./assets/Stage 1.mp4 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '

Comment: I'm 100% sure, because the demo described above works _(I built it)_. can you share the import line in your question or in the comment? I would check if the file path is correct, the error message suggests  one quote mark **'** seems to be wrong, missing or too much _(may be even in the line above)._

Comment: **btw.:** you don't need the url-loader, the code and plugins I posted is all you would need.

Comment: I got ths error : Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module.rules[0].type should be one of these:
   "javascript/auto" | "javascript/dynamic" | "javascript/esm" | "json" | "webassembly/experimental"
   -> Module type to use for the module

Comment: it is hard to say without seeing the code where the problem is, that why I uploaded this small demo to a [github repo](https://github.com/akumagamo/html-quick-demo/tree/main),  if you follow the guide it should work. _(the `package.json`, should contain all the packages needed in the correct versions)_

Comment: @a_7md.f did the demo work? do you has some issues with the code?